# Kalman filter for curves smoothing

Tags: kalman-filter

I have always heard that Kalman filter can be used for curve smoothing. In simple terms, given some curves function of discrete time points $\mathcal{C}_{a}(t_i)$, $\mathcal{C}_{b}(t_i)$, $\mathcal{C}_{c}(t_i)$ $i \in \mathbb{N}$ what I understand is that a new curve let's say $\mathcal{C}(t_i)$ can be obtained by some combination of the 3 previous curves to a get a smooth curve, using Kalman filter.

I have no knowledge of Kalman filters and would like some guidance on how to achieve curve smoothing without dwelling in the deep technical details of Kalman filters due to time restrictions.

Appreciate any hints

Comment: Have you tried other smoothing techniques? Kalman can be great but you need to specify various quantities for the algorithm which in general are not trivial to do. I have used kalman filter   But also used [Savitzky-Golay](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky–Golay_filter) you can use this implementation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) which helped with few missing points in consecutive order.